# Apache POI does not update formulas

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI library to use some formulas from the excel sheet but it seems that the formulas are not being updated at a runtime. If I save a workbook and reopen it, they are recalculated. Is there a way to calculate them at a runtime?

My code is:

```
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);

datatypeSheet.getRow(19).getCell(2).setCellValue(0);  // set C20=0
workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true); 

System.out.println(workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(19).getCell(8).getNumericCellValue()); // prints out the result

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
```

I also tried:

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();
evaluator.notifySetFormula(workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(19).getCell(8));
evaluator.evaluate(workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(19).getCell(8));
```

but they always return old value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation` explicitly only forces the recalculation process to `Excel` while next time opening the workbook. So works as designed.

But using the `FormulaEvaluator` is the correct way. But you should use `FormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell` instead of `FormulaEvaluator.evaluate`.

From [FormulaEvaluator.evaluate](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluate-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-):

> If cell contains a formula, the formula is evaluated and returned,
> else the CellValue simply copies the appropriate cell value from the
> cell and also its cell type.

There is nothing updating the result of the formula in the cell.

In opposite [FormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateFormulaCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-):

> If cell contains formula, it evaluates the formula, and saves the
> result of the formula. The cell remains as a formula cell.

There the result of the formula in the cell is also saved.

Following works for me when in second sheet of `ExcelExample.xlsx` cell `C20` contains a number and cell `I20` contains a formula having `C20` as a parameter.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ExcelEvaluateCell {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExample.xlsx"));
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();  
 
  System.out.println(workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(19).getCell(2).getNumericCellValue()); // prints value of C20
  
  System.out.println(workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(19).getCell(8).getCellFormula()); // prints formula in I20
  System.out.println(workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(19).getCell(8).getNumericCellValue()); // prints result of formula in in I20
  
  workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(19).getCell(2).setCellValue(0); // set C20 = 0
  
  evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(19).getCell(8)); // evaluates formula in cell I20 and updates the result
  System.out.println(workbook.getSheetAt(1).getRow(19).getCell(8).getNumericCellValue()); // prints new result of formula in in I20
 
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./ExcelExampleNew.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```